# Ajax DataSource Date Difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I requested a data via Ajax and the return I mapped it on a table. I tried computing for date difference in a column. Tried some items but to no avail. Would like to seek you advice and or assistance.

Here's my Ajax

```
ajax: {
  url: "{{ route('admin.tickets.index') }}",
  data: {
    'status': searchParams.get('status'),
    'priority': searchParams.get('priority'),
    'category': searchParams.get('category')
  }
},
columns: [
   { data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at' },   <--- I tried to Compute this
   { data: 'process_start', name: 'process_start' },
   { data: 'process_end', name: 'process_end' }
]
```

Computation should be Date now minus created_at date so I can get the age of the ticket itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like [datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) - is that correct?

Comment: Why not include the calculated date in your data?  I'm *guessing* "a data" should be "some data" and is not a typo for "a date"